# dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent not triggered

Tags: java, android, android-activity, view, accessibility

I'm trying to implement accessibility feature in my app. I'm confused about how it actually works. I've a simple imageView in different package from where I send events as:

```
public final void onClick(final android.view.View v) {
            android.util.Log.v(CLASSNAME,"onClick tag:"+v.getTag());
            v.sendAccessibilityEvent(android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED);
```

I've implmented Accessibility class as follows:

```
import android.content.Context;

public final class Accessibility extends android.view.View {
     public Accessibility(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }



    public static android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager manager = (android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager)getSystemService(android.content.Context.ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE); 
    public static android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent event = android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent.obtain();

    public static Accessibility accessibility;


    public static boolean isEenabled()
    {

    if(manager.isEnabled())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent(android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent event)
    {
        super.dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent(event);
        android.util.Log.e(CLASSNAME, "Came here");
                        {

            event.getText().add("Click here!!");
            event.setEnabled(true);
                            return true;
        }
```

I read the Developer docs and I have to override the method in View class (that's the reason I extended my class to View). I realized this method also exists in Activity class (i.e. extends Activity) which calls this method without even sending any events.

I know I'm doing something silly, but not able to find where exactly.

P.S.: I did set a breakpoint on v.sendAccessibilityEvent - It goes to View.java and somehow it fails at condition "AccessibilityManager.getInstance(mContext)!= null"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it is not called is because the system calls dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent of your ImageView(because you send the event from there), not the one of your Accessibility object.

To implement custom accessibility behavior you have 3 options:

1. Implement a custom View that extends ImageView(and override the dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent method and other accessibility). This is a more generic approach and lets the developer imitate system widgets accessibility behavior.

   Here's an example class that adds custom text to the event object on `TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED` event. You need to set its clickable attribute to true so it can receive clicked events. I've overridden `onPopulateAccessibilityEvent` rather than `dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent` because this class doesn't have children and there's no need to override dispatching algorithm.

   ```
   public class CustomImageView  extends ImageView {

       private static final String TAG = CustomImageView.class.getSimpleName();

       /* Here are constructors from ImageView */

       @Override
       public void onPopulateAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
           super.onPopulateAccessibilityEvent(event);

           if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED) {
               Log.v(TAG, "Populating accessibility event");
               event.getText().add("Custom text from onPopulateAccessibilityEvent");
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Implement [AccessibilityDelegate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.AccessibilityDelegate.html). This is not as generic as the first method, but for simple applications it's easier and allows more complex accessibility behavior.

   Here's an AccessibilityDelegate that does similar thing to the CustomImageView. The main advantage is that you can reuse same AccessibilityDelegate for different objects and classes.

   ```
   imageView.setAccessibilityDelegate(new View.AccessibilityDelegate() {
       @Override
       public void onPopulateAccessibilityEvent(View host, AccessibilityEvent event) {
           super.onPopulateAccessibilityEvent(host, event);

           if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED) {
               Log.v(TAG, "Populating accessibility event");
               event.getText().add("Custom text from AccessibilityDelegate");
           }
       }
   });
   ```
3. Combine both methods if you need a very complex accessibility logic.

There are many accessibility methods in View, read documentation carefully which ones you really need to override.

Comment: Thanks, but what is the difference between dispatchPopulateAccessibility method of class Activity and of class View?

Comment: Basically they serve the same purpose. The method processes AccessibilityEvents(of various types, not only click events) before they're passed to the system(and maybe the event source children first). The difference would be the source of the events.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still having problems with implementing the first step. Would you please show how do I go about it, if possible in my code itself? I'm so sorry but I'm stuck here from past three days.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used the second method and it did fire the event. :) .. Now I am using this under onClick(View view) method of ImageView. However, if I set it outside of the image, it does not capture any event (such as TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED). Also, do I need to use sendAccessibilityEvent() method anywhere? Thanks again.

Comment: You need sendAccessibilityEvent if it is not normally triggered by user actions(e.g. click on a View object usually triggers TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED event, but if you have a SurfaceView with objects drawn on it, they won't trigger any events normally).

As for 'I set it outside of the image', I'm not sure I understand - could you elaborate it a bit more?

Comment: Never mind. I realized my mistake. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Sorry for reviving year-old thread. So, if I implement method 1 and if TalkBack is already enabled, the phone is supposed to read out the text "Custom text from onPopulateAccessibilityEvent" when CustomImageView is clicked, correct? Or, do I have to manually execute Text-to-Speech?